# Problema con LIVE USB en Kali Linux. File system Read Only

Tags: linux, filesystem

Buenos días,
tengo un usb que acabo de hacer booteable con Kali Linux, entre las opciones quería iniciar el sistema en modo persistente, pero me lanza un error que no es compatible con mi tarjeta de video Nvidia, con lo cual tuve que iniciar Kali en modo de graficos mas bajo. El problema es que este modo no es modo persistente, con lo cual cada vez que apago y enciendo todo se borra.
Estoy intentado modificar el archivo live.cfg para añadir el parametro `nomodeset vga=normal` y asi intentar que pueda iniciar en modo persistente.
Intento hacer el comando `sudo mount -o remount,rw /lib/live/mount/medium/`
 o `sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdc1` pero en ambos la respuesta del terminal es la siguiente `mount: cannot remount /dev/sdc1 read-write, is write-protected`.
El live usb lo realice desde linux con el comando `dd if=kali.iso of=/dev/sdc bs=512k`.
Adjunto una imagen de Gparted con las particiones que esto crea.
[image: gparted]

La idea es que el sistema de ficheros pase de read only a read write.
De igual modo intente pasar por paramentro al iniciar Kali en el menu de grub pulsando la letra '**e**' pero no hace nada como puede hacer en Ubuntu que aparece los parametros de arranque del kernel.
Un saludo.